# Adding the same variable with different values from a .txt file (python)

Tags: python, filter, import

In python

So for example I have the variables X, Y and Z in a `.txt` file in the following format:

```py
random text
random text
X: 123
Y: 300
random text
X: 22
Y: 34
Z 458.000 random text
random text
```

How would I go about adding the values to the proper variables? So that I get `X = 123 + 22` and `Y = 300 + 34`

Currently I have:

```py
with open('F:/Software/ogamebot/expocounter/allexpo.txt', 'r') as file:
        expo_file = file.read()

    print(expo_file)
```

But whats the best way to continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do. My interpretation is this: you have a set of pre-defined named variables. If a line in the file begins with the name of a variable, then you want to add the subsequent value to the variable. Specifically, there will be some whitespace between the name of the variable and the value given. The following code implements this interpretation:

```py
with open('F:/Software/ogamebot/expocounter/allexpo.txt', 'r') as file: # open the file
    lines = list(file) # get a list of lines of text
    variables = {'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Z': 0} # define our variables in a dictionary (all initially 0)
    for line in lines: # iterate over each line
        for var_name in variables:
            # for each variable, check if the line begins with that variable name
            if line.startswith(var_name): 
                variables[var_name] += float(line.split()[1])
                # if so, add the value to that variable
                # line.split() splits the line into elements based on whitespace
                # we then take the second element, and convert it to a number
    print(variables) # output the results
```

This certainly works for your specific example, but is it what you wanted in general? For example, will there always be whitespace between the variable name and the value? Also note that this code won't load the values into python variables (i.e. `X` is stored as `variables['X']` rather than just `X`) - this would be harder to do in a neat way.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if you have a fixed pattern for variables definition in text file like `VAR: VALUE` here is my code for calculate it without base on predefined variables name.

Source Data:

```
# allexpo.txt

random text
random text
X: 123
Y: 300
A: 101
John: 200
random text
X: 22
Y: 34
Z: 458.000 random text
John: 400
random text
```

Here is the code:

#### Step 0

getting your data from file

```
with open('allexpo.txt', 'r') as file:
    expo_file = file.read()

print(expo_file)
```

#### Step 1

```
import re
arr = [i.split(': ') for i in '.'.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]*: [0-9]*', expo_file)).split('.')]
print(arr)

# it gives you structure like this:
# [['X', '123'], ['Y', '300'], ['A', '101'], ['John', '200'], ['X', '22'], ['Y', '34'], ['Z', '458'], ['John', '400']]
```

#### Step 2

```
arr1 = [(i[0], float(i[1])) for i in arr]
print(arr1)

# it gives you structure like this:
# [('X', 123.0), ('Y', 300.0), ('A', 101.0), ('John', 200.0), ('X', 22.0), ('Y', 34.0), ('Z', 458.0), ('John', 400.0)]
```

#### Step 3

```
var = {k:sum([v[1] for v in arr1 if v[0] == k]) for k in set([i[0] for i in arr1]) }
print(var)

# it gives you desire result:
# {'Z': 458.0, 'John': 600.0, 'Y': 334.0, 'X': 145.0, 'A': 101.0}
```

ultimately it is a three lines of code! :)